# How to globally map a keyboard key to a string in Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I’m using Linux mint and would like to know how to map a keyboard key to an arbitrary string, so that I can—for example—press F4 and the system would act as if I had typed my email address instead regardless of which program currently has input focus.

Comment: Wich window manager ?

Comment: Cinnamon / Mutter / Muffin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this tool called [Autokey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/)

It might be possible with X keyboard tools too - see [Linux keyboard tools](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_keyboard_tools.html)

Comment: I tried to use xbindkeys to map a keypress to starting a command, and letting that command be xvkbd, which can simulate keypresses. Many programs did not aknowledge those keypresses though.  Autokey apparently uses a more compatible way of sending them (and only one program was needed). package name (for apt-get): autokey-qt